# How to add site logo to wordpress displayed on the top left of the site name on the chrome tab or any other web browser?

Tags: plugins, logo

I want my site to have logo like when i go to google.com it shows the google logo with google at the tabs on top of browser. How can I achieve this for my wordpress site ?

Comment: This is called a "favicon" and is nothing unique to WordPress. Create the appropriate files and drop them in the root directory of your WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A favicon? You can set it in *Appearance > Customize > Site Identity > Site Icon*.

Answer (score 0):

Also I think just uploading a favicon.ico to root folder will do it.